# Setup cookie on Chrome even without HTTPS

Tags: cookies, google-chrome

I need to setup a cookie, however Chrome lately seems to accept them only through HTTPS. The "setcookie" function I use works everywhere except Chrome. If I move to HTTPS, it results as properly set up.

I tried to understand how WordPress works then, checking https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_auth_cookie/ and copied a bit of its parameters.

the final code is

```
$secure = (is_ssl() && 'https' === parse_url(get_option('home'), PHP_URL_SCHEME)); 
setcookie($name, $value, $expiration, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, $secure, true);
```

This is still not working though, what am I missing?

Comment: Where are you trying to hook this function?

Comment: Is not a matter of hooks, I'm creating a cookie in an AJAX call performed by frontend users

Comment: you can't use php `setcookie` after headers have been sent. use javascript to set the cookie.

Comment: Probably I was not clear: the AJAX call is handled in the "init" hook, way before headers. The setcookie() system perfectly works, it's just a Chrome block if website is not using HTTPS. However, **since WP login (cookie-based, as far as I know) works** ... how to achieve the same result?

Comment: setcookie only requires (name, value).  With that said, how can an ajax call being on the frontend happen before init?  Ajax is a frontend action, which must by nature happen after the page is rendered. You should probably include more of your code and function for this to make sense.